# Statiscal test for ranking time series based on change points and values

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, trend

I have five time series, each of which consisting of 30 measurements (pressure) from sensors (on three machines located at five different locations). I would like to rank those time series. I run a regression on each time series, all of them have the same slope and y intercept. However, some time series may have different values around the regression line. Some may also have a couple of change points My question are the following:
What is the statistical test that can be used to rank time series with the same linear regression coefficients (slope and y intercept). My ranking should be based on the presence or not of multiple change points  as well as around the values around the regression line. I search a little bit and I found this
[Similarity of trends in time series analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13835924/similarity-of-trends-in-time-series-analysis). I do not know if it applies to my problem as I also have some change points in some time series. I am not sure that change point are taken into account for those solutions.

Comment: This is hard to follow & will be hard to answer. Can you provide your data or plots or any additional information?